# How to succinctly state that someone is not an “X”?

Tags: punctuation

If I want to say that a person is not an engineer can I call him non-engineer?
And how about the punctuation, I must use hyphen? And / or capitalize?

I want to use the word somewhere to tell that people who are not engineers can also understand the text

Comment: Yes you can call such a person a *non-engineer*, it's immediately understandable that the term refers to those who are not engineers.  Yes the hyphen is necessary - what's a *nonengineer* ?  And you only need to capitalise when you would otherwise capitalise *engineer*, such as at the beginning of a sentence

Comment: The title of this question does not match the question itself.

Comment: I know. I had written a different title which matched my question. But someone, who had nothing else to do, made his mission to change it to this title, also by using a fancy word like succint etc.... I am sure he feels happy now....

Answer (score 3):

You can also use the word **layman** about which [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/layman) says

> **layman**
>   NOUN
>
> **2** A person without professional or specialized knowledge in a particular subject.
>
> *the book seems well suited to the interested layman*

Comment: Also “muggle”, if you’re feeling particularly informal. 

Comment: I know the word layman. But that is not suitable for my purpose. I want to specifically say a person who is not an engineer.

Answer (score 0):

I'd tend to use **non-technical** over **lay person** as I find it clearer.

It does not directly assume a lack of understanding, but prefers an assumption that the person is not a technician or engineer for the application.